# How to "edit" a external object in a function

Tags: c#, function

I have this code :

```
CreaPager(m_oPacchettiEnum, 1, 10);

private void CreaPager(IEnumerable enPass, int limiteUp, int limiteDown)
{
    enPass= enPass.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp);
}
```

and I'd like, when I edit `enPass`, reflect the edit to `m_oPacchettiEnum`, without have a return `IEnumerable<T>` function.

So, edit directly m_oPacchettiEnum trought the function. I use to do it on C, don't know if is possible on C# (but I think so).

I read somethings about using `out`, but seems that it doesnt work :

```
CreaPager(out m_oPacchettiEnum, 1, 10);

private void CreaPager(out IEnumerable enPass, int limiteUp, int limiteDown)
{
    enPass= enPass.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp);
}
```

Comment: enum is a c# keyword, rename it to something else

Comment: already tried! It doesnt resolve the problem...

Comment: You can use `ref` but please, just return `IEnumerable` instead. It's so much cleaner.

Comment: I can't! On that function I need to return also a string...

Comment: @markzzz, I went OO, now you can return what you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`out` doesn't work here because you can't use an `out` parameter in the method until it's been assigned. Since your assignment uses `enum` (which you should rename) as part of the right-hand-side, it's not allowed. Switching `out` to `ref` will make things work.

**However**. As I mentioned in my answer to your previous (now deleted) question, please don't do this. It is *much* more idiomatic when working with sequences to return a new `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
var newQuery = CreaPager(m_oPacchettiEnum, 1, 10);

private void CreaPager<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumeration, int limiteUp, int limiteDown)
{
    return enumeration.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp);
}
```

As well, you can make the method an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) by preceding the first parameter with `this`:

```
private void CreaPager<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, int limiteUp, int limiteDown) { .. }
```

Doing so would allow you to integrate your method into a LINQ-to-Objects call chain:

```
var query = myEnumerable.Where(x => x.OtherProp == 1).CreaPager(1, 10).Select(x => x.SomeProp);
```

**EDIT**: Since you need to also return a `string`, make *that* the `out` parameter:

```
private void CreaPager<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, int limiteUp, int limiteDown, out string myString)
{
    myString = "foo";
    return enumeration.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp);
}
```

You'd call the method like this:

```
string theString;
var newQuery = CreaPager(m_oPacchettiEnum, 1, 10, out theString);
```

`out` is fine here, since I'm assuming you don't need to both use and assign the string. And if you do, then I would suggest you split it into two parameters anyway.

Comment: +1 for recommending against modifying the object ref in place instead of returning the new collection

Comment: I can't return the enumration, because I'm also returning a string.

Comment: @markzzz if that's the case, then you should just make the `string` the `out` parameter.

Comment: dlev : so there isnt so much differences :)

Comment: @markzzz Between `ref` and `out`, the differences are minimal, since they are actually compiled down to the same thing (a `byref` parameter.) The difference between passing the string out and passing the enumeration out is that the enumeration *already has data in it*, while the string would (hopefully) not. I think you may want to refactor your method so you don't have *any* `out`/`ref` parameters, but if you *must* have one, then the `string` parameter is preferable.

Comment: And how can I catch the out string when I call the function?

Comment: I really can't see the big differences between the two methods in my context :)

Comment: Also, the `this` solution seems to doesnt works : "Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class", and my method must be static...

Comment: @markzzz That's true. The extension method part isn't necessary, though. Feel free to remove that (or follow the error message and place it in a static class.)

Answer (score 4):

Use `ref` instead of `out`:

```
CreaPager(ref m_oPacchettiEnum, 1, 10);

private void CreaPager(ref IEnumerable enum, int limiteUp, int limiteDown)
{
    enum = enum.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp);
}
```

Comment: This would work and is what is being asked for but, what happens when you want the next "Pager"?

Comment: originally `m_oPacchettiEnum` holds the "complete" set. `CreaPager` limits `m_oPacchettiEnum` within some bounds. Later I would like to limit `m_oPaccettiEnum` within different bounds but my orginal "complete" set has been replaced.

Answer (score 2):

@Serge answer would work but wouldn't it be better to do this

```
IEnumerable pager = CreaPager(m_oPacchetti, 1, 10);

private IEnumerable CreaPager(IEnumerable pachetti, int limiteUp, in limiteDown)
{
    return pachetti.Skip(limiteDown).Take(limiteUp - limiteDown);
}
```

That way you can reuse `m_oPachetti` and you avoid the nasty reference passing and the code is easier to read.

**EDIT:**

How about, since "Pager" is an italian noun??? 
Pager is an IEnumerable, you could also extend the functionality rather than passing the string in.

```
string theString = "TheStringYouNeedToReturn";
Pager<?> pager = new Pager<?>(m_oPacchetti, 1, 10);

private class Pager<T> : List<T>
{
    private Pager(){}

    public Pager(IEnumerable<T> pachetti, 
                   int limiteUp, 
                   int limiteDown, 
                   string aString)
    {
        this.AString = astring;
        this.AddRange(pachetti.Skip(limiteUp).Take(limiteUp - limiteDown);
    }

    public string AString {get; private set;}

}
```

Comment: I can't do it. Is what I'd like to get rid! I need to return also a string :)